# Suggestions about a Database conception

Tags: database, database-design, uml, entity-relationship, informix

I am on a project to create a new Java EE application (JSF, Hibernate, Spring Security, Informix database). This application will automate the entry of notes for the annual interview of bank employees.

At the very beginning, everything was entered in an Excel file which then generated a report with the various performance graphs (according to the notes entered from 0 to 4).

Now I want to do a fairly optimized database design. I thought of creating the following tables:

- `Interview` with columns `(interview_id, interview_date)`,
- `Competency` with columns `(competency_id, competency_group, competency_name)`,
- `Interview_note` with columns  `(interview_note_id, employee_id (FK), interview_id (FK) , competency_id (FK))`

However, I have some doubts about how to keep it compact and logical. Is this the right way of doing things?  Are there any improvements to take into account for more optimization?

Comment: Since you asked for opinions I voted to close this for being opinion-based.

Comment: humm this is a bit of an ask -- you're wanting free consultancy in effect. Have you got any fellow analysts/developers you could spit ball design options with?

Comment: Won't the interview table need to record at least the identity of the person interviewed, and probably the person interviewing?  You'll probably want a table to identify competency groups, IMO.  The interview note table won't need the employee identity if there's only one employee involved in an interview.

Comment: I voted to close because it does not state a specific problem, just a feeling that the solution may be improved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your narrative and draft database schema, I find the following identified entities: `Employee`, `Competency`, `Interview` and `Interview_note`.

In this regard, only the `Employee` table is missing, but I'm sure you have it somewhere.  Moreover, your design is very flexible,  since it allows for several `Interview_notes` of the same interview, competence and employee. What is perhaps missing therefore, is the `id` of who made the notes.  Alternatively, if there's only one set of notes for an interview,  you could consider to identify the interviewer in `Interview`.

A part from that, and maybe some missing data for the note (points, percentage of satisfaction, or some textual annotations?) your design seems to fulfil its purposes.

The database engine will very well optimize all the joins you'll have to do.  Maybe facilitate its job by defining the `_id` as primary key, if you didn't do it.

I can't see other optimizations:  each table clearly represent a different relation (in the relational algebra meaning of the term) and merging any of them would inevitably result in a suboptimal redundant schema.

Comment: The OP speaks about FK so by *definition* they refer to PK and for instance *interview_id* must be a PK, or this is only in Sql ?

Comment: @bruno Is what only in SQL? PS In the relational model, a FK references a CK, one of which can be a PK, but also arbitrary constraints can be declared. In SQL a FK references a UNIQUE, one of which can be a PK. PS The question dosn't fully say what the tables mean or what FKs reference. But I'd agree that we are likely supposed to guess at certain meanings & FK targets.

Comment: @philipxy yes exactly! And thanks for your additional info. Indeed, I just mentioned PK as a precaution (therefore “if you didn’t do it”):  OP  said it was a FK so I assumed PK/FK, but on the other side there was no objective evidence that the tables where created with FK constraint (missing references), so no guarantee that there would be a PK or even an index, and moreover OP suggest he was not very experienced with db design.

Comment: @bruno sorry, I lost your notification yesterday so I didn’t answer before. See my comment to Philipxy for the explanation